# I am completely new to python and I tried installing django today after installing pip and a virtual environment and I get this errors

Tags: python, django, pip

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\seunj\desktop\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 215, in main

    status = self.run(options, args)

  File "c:\users\seunj\desktop\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py", line 335, in run

    wb.build(autobuilding=True)
  File "c:\users\seunj\desktop\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\wheel.py", line 749, in build


    self.requirement_set.prepare_files(self.finder)
  File "c:\users\seunj\desktop\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 380, in prepare_files

    ignore_dependencies=self.ignore_dependencies))
  File "c:\users\seunj\desktop\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 620, in _prepare_file
    session=self.session, hashes=hashes)

  File "c:\users\seunj\desktop\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\download.py", line 821, in unpack_url

    hashes=hashes
  File "c:\users\seunj\desktop\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\download.py", line 659, in unpack_http_url

    hashes)
  File "c:\users\seunj\desktop\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\download.py", line 882, in _download_http_url

    _download_url(resp, link, content_file, hashes)
  File "c:\users\seunj\desktop\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\download.py", line 603, in _download_url

    hashes.check_against_chunks(downloaded_chunks)
  File "c:\users\seunj\desktop\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\utils\hashes.py", line 46, in check_against_chunks

    for chunk in chunks:
  File "c:\users\seunj\desktop\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\download.py", line 571, in written_chunks

    for chunk in chunks:
  File "c:\users\seunj\desktop\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\utils\ui.py", line 139, in iter

    for x in it:
  File "c:\users\seunj\desktop\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\download.py", line 560, in resp_read

    decode_content=False):
  File "c:\users\seunj\desktop\venv\lib\site-
packages\pip\_vendor\requests\packages\urllib3\response.py", line 357, in stream
    data = self.read(amt=amt, decode_content=decode_content)

  File "c:\users\seunj\desktop\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\packages\urllib3\response.py", line 324, in read
    flush_decoder = True

  File "c:\users\seunj\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\Lib\contextlib.py", line 100, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)

  File "c:\users\seunj\desktop\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\packages\urllib3\response.py", line 237, in _error_catcher

    raise ReadTimeoutError(self._pool, None, 'Read timed out.')

pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions.ReadTimeoutError: 
HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.python.org', port=443): Read timed out.
```

Comment: Please your answers will be highly appreciated

Comment: pip is not allowed to access the internet, you need to allow it from your firewall to use the internet

Comment: There seems to be a problem with your internet connection. Check your internet and do pip install django again

Comment: If you're using windows, I recommend using Anaconda. It handles some issues that windows has with python very nicely.

Comment: Well, DragonBobz, I am hearing that for the first time I will google that immediately thanks

Answer (score 4):

> `HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.python.org', port=443): Read timed out.`

This sums it up. It is a network connectivity problem. Some packages cannot be installed because the server is inaccessible. I assume it's a transient problem, else you won't be able to install the rest of the packages. I suggest that you try again, after fixing firewall rules, or checking other internet connection settings.